# Given two lists of objects, how do I compare into new KV in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, set-difference

I used except to find the modified objects, but except takes a comparator and only returns the difference.

What is the best algorithm to return such result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you have two `KeyValuePair` like that:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

What you want is a simply joining two sequence based on matching keys. For this you can use [`Enumerable.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.100).aspx). Then, you just need to filter the result with `Where()` method:

```
var result = list2.Join(list1, x => x.Key, y => y.Key, (x, y) => new { x, y })
                  .Where(l => l.x.Value != l.y.Value)
                  .ToList();
```

Or, as a second option you can just iterate over the second list and get matching elements in the first list:

```
var result = list2.Where(x => list1.Any(y => y.Key == x.Key && y.Value != x.Value))
     .Select(x => new
     {
         NewKVP = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value),
         OldKVP = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, list1.Single(z => z.Key == x.Key).Value)
     })
    .ToList();
```

But, I prefer `Join()`.